# Help me to understand statistical testing

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, primality-test

Why does a statistical test returns the p value?

I am looking at the Diebold-Mariano-Test (DM Test):
https://github.com/johntwk/Diebold-Mariano-Test

Basically, this test gives me a DM statistics, and also the p value. So, do I just use the p-value to judge a null hypthoesis?

For instance, if p-val > alpha = 0.05, then I reject the null hypothesis, is this correct?

Comment: Do you know what a $P$-value represents?

Comment: P-value it is used to reject a test. I am wondering how does this related to the test-statiscs (in this case, the DM)

Comment: Not quite. A [$P$-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) represents the probability that we observe a given result (or something more extreme) assuming that the null hypothesis is true. Often, when a decision is to be made, we _choose_ to reject our null hypothesis when this probability is less than a certain per-determined significance level, usually denoted $\alpha$.